# node request returns ECONNREFUSED

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I am new to nodejs and express. I am using "request" library to read content of google.com.  I keep getting connection refused error. I took the code from https://github.com/request/request

This is my first_request.js file:

```
    var request = require('request');
    request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
  console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
});
```

To run, I got to the folder and do `node first_request.js`

it give me error as:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs when you have a proxy set up. The link works fine on my computer. You can set your proxy options with `request.defaults({})`. You should specify user credentials + host and port.

```
var request = require('request');

var link = "http://www.google.com";

var proxyUrl = "http://" + user + ":" + password + "@" + host + ":" + port;

var proxiedRequest = request.defaults({'proxy': proxyUrl});

proxiedRequest(link , function (error, response, body) {
    //handle the response..
})
```